# Can I use Express to create client application?

Tags: node.js, rest, express

Can I use Express to create client application and connect it to API created by express or I have to use Angular or React to create the client app ? Thank you

Comment: Express is a ***web server*** framework.  It is only used to implement a server.  That server can certainly connect to some API to do its work and the server itself could serve web UI pages, but the server itself will NOT be a client.  You would have to use some other client to connect to your Express server.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform server-side rendering with express to render client applications from express. Look into server-side rendering.